# Why don't these threads run in order?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

When I run this code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        workers.emplace_back([i]
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::cout << "Hi from thread " << i << std::endl;
        });
    }

    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [] (std::thread& t)
    { t.join(); });
}
```

I get the [output](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fCN7yigWoprULRPS):

```c++
Hi from thread 7
Hi from thread 1
Hi from thread 4
Hi from thread 6
Hi from thread 0
Hi from thread 5
Hi from thread 2
Hi from thread 3
Hi from thread 9
Hi from thread 8
```

Even though I used a mutex to keep only one thread access at a time. Why isn't the output in order?

Comment: one thread access at a time have nothing to do with starting order

Comment: Mutex prevents two of them from running that piece of code simultaneously.  But why do you expect any particular order?

Comment: "Only one thread access at a time" is exactly what you achieved. But why did you expect it to happen in some specific order?

Comment: @AndreyT I figured if one thread had access at a time, the first thread would get `i` at value `0`, the second at value `1`, and so on.

Comment: If order matters, then why would you use threads?

Comment: The thread at workers[0] has i equal to 0. But it might not execute first.

Comment: @template boy: "One thread had access at a time"... Access to what? If you made `i` a global variable and made your threads read and increment `i` inside the locked region, then indeed the first thread would get `0` from `i`, the second would get `1` and so on. But your code is not written like that. You assign values of `i` to your threads before they even start. And they you start them. There's no way to predict which thread (with which value of `i`) will race ahead of the others.

Comment: @AndreyT What do you mean "before they even start"? Doesn't the thread start when I create it?

Comment: @template boy: It does, but that's irrelevant. What I'm talking about is the lambda function that you use as the thread function. First, you create a lambda function, which *captures* `i` by value. There's no thread yet. But the value of `i` is already captured (stored internally) by the thread function (by your lambda). Then you create a thread from that lambda function (and, as you correctly noted, the thread immediately starts). But the value of `i` is already captured by that time.

Comment: @AndreyT A video tutorial I read said that `std::async()` is not a thread. I know it returns a future, but doesn't it have a thread inside it in order for it to run asynchronously?

Comment: @template boy: Is this intended to be an unrelated question? Anyway, `std::async` will use a thread internally if it is explicitly requested to run asynchroniously.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What your mutex achieves is that no two threads print at the same time. However, they are still racing for which thread acquires the mutex first.

If you want to have serial execution you can just avoid threads at all.

Answer (score 6):

It is totally up to the operating system in which order threads are scheduled. You can not rely on any order. Assume it is totally random.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a lambda to emplace_back which is used as a parameter for the std::thread constructor.  See the details for emplace_back copy/pasted below from cppreference.com.

"Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed through std::allocator_traits::construct, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container. The arguments args... are forwarded to the constructor as std::forward(args)...."

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

The mutex in the body of the lambda has no affect until the std::thread object has been fully constructed and running the thread entry point defined by the lambda body.  Some of the std::threads could start running during the loop, or the threads might not start until after the loop completes. You can't figure this out in a portable way.

After the for-loop constructs all your std::threads in your vector, it is up to the OS to decide in what order the threads are scheduled to run and that is how you get the random ordering of your output.

Answer (score 2):

The execution order is immaterial, you cannot predict it and it will change from run to run and over time in a given run.

Your designs should never depend on thread execution order in any way or form.

It goes further than that: if N threads are waiting on a synchronization object, say a mutex, and the mutex gets released, there is no way to reliably and portably predict which of the waiting threads will be awaken and grab the mutex next, irrespectively of their relative scheduling priorities.

Non-determinism makes multithreaded programming difficult :-)