# c++ 11 Threads different behaviour on linux and windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, multithreading, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mx;
void some_function()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mx_guard(mx);
        std::cout << "some_function()\n";
    }
}

void some_other_function()
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mx_guard(mx);
        std::cout << "some_other_function\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(some_function);
    std::thread t2 = std::move(t1); //t2 will be joined

    t1 = std::thread(some_other_function);

    if(t2.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "t2 is joinable()\n";
        t2.join(); //calling join for t1
    }
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "t1 is joinable()\n";
        t1.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have different output for this program on windows and linux. On windows using visual studio 13 compiler i get the following output.

```
some_function()
some_other_function
some_function()
some_other_function
some_function()
some_other_function
some_function()
some_other_function
some_function()
some_other_function
some_function()
some_other_function
```

But on linux using gcc the output is different

```
some_function()
some_function()
some_function()
some_function()
some_function()
some_function()
some_function()
some_other_function
some_other_function
some_other_function
some_other_function
some_other_function
some_other_function
some_other_function
```

On windows two threads print one by one but on linux it's not the same behavior. Use of mutex on linux does not synchronize. How to synchronize on linux?

Comment: How many CPUs does your system have? Order of execution between threads is not guaranteed.

Comment: "Use of mutex on linux does not synchronize" - you can't conclude that from that output. At all.

Comment: What are you *exactly* planning to do? We can't help you if all you provide is boilerplate.

Comment: `std::cout << "some_function()\n";` You're missing a `cout.flush()` after your outputs, that might well explain the different behavior.

Comment: What do you want to sync? Currently you are syncing access to std::cout and nothing more. Your mutex just guarantee that you won't get output like: "some_funsome_other_function\nction()\n"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't these threads run in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282125/why-dont-these-threads-run-in-order)

Comment: i am new to threads, i was concerned why the behaviors is different for windows and linux. I know mutex is for concurrent access to shared resource.I was worried with the windows output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `mutex` is simply a lock for preventing concurrent access to a shared resource, in this case std::cout. And in both cases, only one thread is writing to `std::cout` at a time. While it's possible that under some circumstances unlocking a mutex may result in waking another task, it is not something you should expect or rely on unless you are responsible for the OS/scheduler code yourself.

The mutex *is* restricting access to std::cout: If you run the same code without the lock-guard you're likely to see garbled/mixed output on one OS or the other.

The fact that you're seeing something like that in Visual Studio is purely coincidental and is not guaranteed, and the fact that you are seeing something else under Linux is more likely to be about differences in how IO is performed than how threads operate.

I'm speculating as to what you are actually trying to do here, but I suspect you want a [condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and `notify_one`. However, you again should not assume that it will round-robin.

Also, `joinable()` tests whether the threads are running, `join()` waits for them to stop, but since your threads are in a permanent loop, the first call to `join()` will hang forever.

--- EDIT ---

When I run your code under Visual Studio 2015 with /O2, I get the same output as you report for Linux.

Comment: if we have infinite loops in two or more thread, then how to join them ? or we should use some flag and based on the some condition variable we should proceed ?

Comment: Well, `join` means "wait for exit", if you changed `while(1)` to `for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)` they will eventually end and `join()` will succeed. The C++ standard doesn't provide a way to explicitly cancel a thread. You can use a `std::shared_future<void>` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) as a way to notify the threads you want them to stop. See http://pastebin.com/uHVWSwyN